# Place objects on a defined shape

Tags: css, html, canvas, area

I'm looking for a way, to allow a drag and drop, only on what's the area of an image.

So, if the image is the following:

[image]

I will have the option to add another layer on top, with some text, but that new layer, can't go anywhere, but inside the shape of that image.

[image]
[image]

So, after some research, I still wonder how can I achieve something like that?
I know I can use `map` and `area` to map existing elements on an image, but how can I add new elements, that fit only to that map? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To illustration your solution, let's assume you want to drop a raindrop in your cloud and be sure all raindrop pixels are fully inside the cloud...**

[image][image]

Then the answer to your question requires asking this question:

> Are all opaque raindrop pixels fully inside the cloud?

To answer this question, you must compare every pixel on the raindrop with every pixel underneath.

- If the raindrop pixel is transparent, then ignore this pixel because this part of the raindrop is transparent anyway.
- If the raindrop pixel is opaque and the pixel underneath is transparent, then this raindrop pixel *is not contained in the cloud*.
- If both the raindrop pixel & underneath pixel are opaque, then this raindrop pixel *is contained in the cloud*.

You can get the required transparency information about the raindrop and cloud by drawing their images on a canvas and then requesting `getImageData`. 'getImageData' returns the red, green, blue & alpha information about every pixel on the canvas. To answer the question, we just need the alpha information.

Here's annotated code and a Demo:

```js
// canvas related variables
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var offsetX,offsetY;

// load the cloud and raindrop images
var cloudmap,rainmap;
var rain=new Image();
rain.crossOrigin='anonymous';
rain.onload=start;
rain.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/raindrop1.png';
var cloud=new Image();
cloud.crossOrigin='anonymous';
cloud.onload=start;
cloud.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/cloud.png";
var cloud1=new Image();
cloud1.crossOrigin='anonymous';
cloud1.onload=start;
cloud1.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/cloud1.png";
var imageCount=3;

function start(){
  if(--imageCount>0){return;}

  // resize the canvas to the size of the cloud
  // and draw the cloud on the canvas
  cw=canvas.width=cloud.width;
  ch=canvas.height=cloud.height;
  draw();

  // create a transparency map of the cloud
  cloudmap={
    width:cloud.width,
    height:cloud.height,
    map:transparencyMap(cloud),
  };   

  // create a transparency map of the raindrop
  rainmap={
    width:rain.width,
    height:rain.height,
    map:transparencyMap(rain),
  }

  // listen for mousemove events
  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

  // listen for window scroll events
  calcCanvasOffset();
  $(window).scroll(function(){ calcCanvasOffset(); });

}


function transparencyMap(img){
  // create a temp canvas sized to the img size
  var c=document.createElement('canvas');
  var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
  c.width=img.width;
  c.height=img.height;
  // draw the img on the canvas
  cctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  // get the pixel data for every pixel on the canvas
  var data=cctx.getImageData(0,0,c.width,c.height).data;
  // create an array that reports the status 
  // of every pixel on the canvas
  // (status: true if opaque, false if transparent)
  var map=[];
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i+=4){
    map.push(data[i+3]>250);
  }
  return(map);
}


function draw(mouseX,mouseY,isContained){
  // draw the cloud
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  if(isContained){
    // draw the blue cloud indicating the raindrop is not fully contained
    ctx.drawImage(cloud,0,0);
  }else{
    // draw the yellow cloud indicating the raindrop is fully contained
    ctx.drawImage(cloud1,0,0);
  }
  // if the mouse position was supplied
  if(mouseX){
    ctx.drawImage(rain,mouseX-rain.width/2,mouseY-rain.height/2);
  }
}


function AcontainsB(ax,ay,amap,bx,by,bmap){
  // set a flag indicating of the raindrop is fully contained in the cloud
  var isContained=true;

  // calc the relative position of the raindrop vs cloud in the canvas
  var deltaX=bx-ax;
  var deltaY=by-ay;

  // test every pixel of B against A
  // if B is opaque and a is not opaque then B is not contained by A
  var y=0;
  while(isContained && y<bmap.height){
    var x=0;
    while(isContained && x<bmap.width){
      // calc the map array indexes for the cloud(A) & raindrop(B)
      var mapIndexA=(y+deltaY)*amap.width+(x+deltaX);
      var mapIndexB=y*bmap.width+x;
      // if the raindrop is opaque at this pixel
      if(bmap.map[mapIndexB]){

        // ...and if this pixel is off canvas
        if(mapIndexA<0 || mapIndexA>=amap.map.length){
          // ...then the raindrop is not in the cloud at this pixel
          isContained=false;
          // ...or if the pixel under the raindrop is transparent 
        }else if(!amap.map[mapIndexA]){
          // ...then the raindrop is not in the cloud at this pixel
          isContained=false;
        }
      }            
      x++;
    }
    y++;
  }
  return(isContained);
}


function handleMouseMove(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // get the current mouse position
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // calc the top-left corner of the raindrop image
  var rainX=parseInt(mouseX-rain.width/2);
  var rainY=parseInt(mouseY-rain.height/2);

  // ask if the raindrop is fully contained in the cloud
  var isContained=AcontainsB(0,0,cloudmap,rainX,rainY,rainmap);


  // redraw the cloud & raindrop
  draw(mouseX,mouseY,isContained);

}


// recalc the canvas offsetX & offsetY
function calcCanvasOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Use the mouse to drag the raindrop over the canvas<br>The cloud turns blue if the rain is fully inside the cloud</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=500></canvas>
```

You can use this "transparency mapping" to test anything you can draw into a canvas including images and text. Note that text is drawn with `context.fillText`.

If you're dropping a text element external to the canvas (maybe using jqueryUI or native "draggable"), you will have to:

1. Fetch the x,y position of the drop.
2. Fetch the text content of the dropped element.
3. Create a temporary canvas containing the text. Do it like this...

   ```
   function textToCanvas(text,fontsize,fontface){
       var c=document.createElement('canvas');
       var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
       cctx.font=fontsize+'px '+fontface;
       var textWidth=cctx.measureText(text).width;
       c.width=textWidth;
       c.height=fontsize+4;
       cctx.font=fontsize+'px '+fontface;
       cctx.textBaseline='top';
       cctx.fillText(text,0,0);
       return(c);
   }
   ```
4. Use the temporary canvas just like an image to create a transparency map. This is possible because the canvas will accept another canvas as its image source.

Good luck with your project.

**[ Additional questions from comments ]**

**Additional Question:**

> "How will this react when you have a raindrop placed somewhere in the
>   cloud (saved it's position), and then you try to add something that's
>   on top of it?" Said another way: "How can I test if 2 objects are
>   overlapping?"

**Answer:** You can test if 2 objects overlap by using transparency maps again. Create another test (AintersectsB) which tests if any pixel in A is opaque while the associated pixel in B is also opaque. You can start with the `AcontainsB` and modify it to create the `AintersectsB` test.

**Additional Question:**

> "How can I save and later restore dropped object positions?"

**Answer:** Since canvas doesn't remember what it draws, you must remember for it. This is usually done by creating a javascript object for each dropped item and saving all these objects in an array. That way if you need to save the positions on a server you can use `JSON.stringify` to turn the array of objects into a string and send that string to the server to be saved in a database (or file). To recreate your work, the server pulls the string from the database and sends it to the browser. The browser uses `JSON.parse` to turn the string back into an array of javascript objects. Then you can redraw the scene exactly as it was using the information in the objects.

Comment: I sincerely could not have expected a more clear and well detailed answer. Absolutely great perspective, BUT, how will this react when you have a raindrop placed somewhere in the cloud (saved it's position), and then you try to add something that's on top of it? I'm testing you're script right now, but your opinion would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Still going through it, but just wanted to ask... how would you recommend me implementing a save and remember position on dragged element, and  that upon refreshing, I'll be able to draw them back?

Comment: You're welcome! I've added to my post to answer your additional questions. Cheers!